# Dart Canvas not drawing image

Tags: javascript, canvas, dart

Attempting to use Canvas and Dart in order to render an image however I am having no luck.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Please see attached code.

```
import 'dart:html';

class Board{

  CanvasElement canvas;
  CanvasRenderingContext2D context;

  Board(){
    canvas = new CanvasElement(width: 600, height: 600);
    context = canvas.context2D;
  }

  getCanvas(){
    return canvas;
  }

  getContext(){
    return context;
  }

}

class Player{

  ImageElement player;
  CanvasRenderingContext2D context;
  CanvasElement canvas;

  Player(theCanvas, theContext){
    canvas = theCanvas;  
    context = theContext;
  }

  drawPlayer(){
    player = new Element.tag("img");
    player.id = "#thePlayer";
    player.src = "img/player.png";
    context.drawImage(player, 100, 100);
  }

  getPlayer(){
    return player;
  }

}

void main() {
  Board b = new Board();
  Player p = new Player(b.getCanvas(), b.getContext());
  p.drawPlayer(); 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the image had not loaded from the server by the time the Dart VM had run.

In order to rectify this, before showing the player I checked the image had loaded.

```dart
player.onLoad.listen( (value) => context.drawImage(player, 0, 0) );
```

Comment: Really useful, thanks, that saved me a lot of hair pulling.  This problem doesn't occur if run locally in Dartium, which is why I didn't notice it till I ran it from an online server, transformed via "pub build" into JS.